# Extending a template from project level in Django

Tags: django, templates

My tree looks like this:

```
Project
   App1
     templates
        App1 (templates here)
   App2
     templates
        App2 (templates here)
   templates (files here)
```

In a template file in app1 (for example), how do I extend from `base.html` (which is in my project's `templates` directory)?  It is automatically looking in my app directory. What I'm trying at the moment is:

```
{% extends '/base.html' %}
```

No big surprise that that's not working.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I solved the problem by adding the directory in Templates, DIR.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "Test1","templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Guess it should have been obviouse.